# Repair of scratch in mirror glass

Tags: scratch

I have quite a scratch, about 1/8in long, in my mirror.

Can I get this removed by a professional, or would the better course be to just save up and buy new ones (they're dimming ones, 350$ each... and I've got scratches on both).

You can see the scratches on this picture:

[image]

I can feel it when I go over them.

Issue is that these are European, blind spot mirrors, so I can't even get them easily replaced here in the US.

Comment: The only thing you can do is get them replaced, as you can't polish it out (in most cases). Mirror glass is *really thin*. Really, if they aren't blocking your vision, just leave it be. When you focus at the reflection in the mirror, you are focussing beyond the scratches and you'll never see them ... at least that's been my experience. At $350/ea, I could learn to live with it.